# Xamarin Studio: How to change the syntax color of unused parameter in method?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

How can i change the syntax color of unused parameter in a method in `Xamarin Studio?` Which the key is to set?

(Hint: Take a look in `Xamarin Studio at: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Syntax Highlighting`.)

Here is some example method:

```
public void SomeMethod(object unused){
    print("hello");
}
```

I want the compiler automatically sets the syntax color of "unused" to red if 
i do not use the parameter in the method body.

After refactoring:

```
public void SomeMethod(){
    print("hello");
}
```

Alternatvily the compiler could throw an error.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible in Xamarin.Studio.

Comment: I don't think that is possible currently